# IBM MQ .net core nuget amqmdnetstd.dll

Tags: .net-core, ibm-mq

How and where can I get the .net core dll for IBM MQ aka `amqmdnetstd.dll`?
Is there any nuget for it? How can I send a message to a queue, I am getting error `2082` when trying to access the queue.

```
queue = mqManager.AccessQueue(queueName, openOptions);
       
          MQQueueManager queueManager = null;
          MQQueue queue=null;
                           try
                           {
                               properties = new Hashtable();
                               properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
                               properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, queueManagerName);
                               properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
                               properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, MQChannel);
                               properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, connectionName);
                               properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "");
               
                                queueManager = new MQQueueManager("MNTSCM01", properties);
                                  quqeue=queueManager .AccessQueue(queueName, openOptions);
               
                           }
                           catch (MQException mqex)
                           {
                               // Console out exception
                           }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 problems:

> How and where i can get the .net core dll for mqserie aka amqmdnetstd.dll

You need MQ 9.1.1 or higher, and if you just want MQ Client capability you could download the whole client or the redistributable client. Pick 9.1.1.0-IBM-MQC-Win64   or 9.1.1.0-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64 
https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~WebSphere&product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere+MQ&release=9.1.1&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=9.1.1.0-IBM-MQC-%2A,9.1.1.0-IBM-MQ-Install-Java-All,9.1.1.0-IBM-MQ-Java-InstallRA&useReleaseAsTarget=true&includeSupersedes=1

> i am getting errors on this 2082 when tryinh to access the queue

mqrc 2082 shows "2082  0x00000822  MQRC_UNKNOWN_ALIAS_BASE_Q", ie you are opening a queue which is an alias queue, but the thing it points to doesnt exist. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q039210_.htm